# Run ngen.exe after Inno install finishes but, before user can launch the app

Tags: inno-setup, ngen

I am able to run the following in the cmd console and it works. I can see the difference when the app is loading and when executing task within.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files (x86)\App Directroy\App.exe"
```

I am trying to have Inno perform the same when installing the app but, before the user has an opportunity to launch the app for the first time.

This is what I have tried so far with Inno:

```
[Run]
Filename: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe; Parameters: "install ""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}""";
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent"
```

What happens is that, when Inno finishes installing it starts the app and doesn't execute the ngen.

I am trying to find how to run the above code in the Inno script.

Am I placing the code in the correct section of the Inno script?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: The code seems correct (except for hard-coded `C:\Windows\...` path). If it does not work for you, include installer log file (`/log=...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read what [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) said about the hard-coded **c:\windows...** and looked into it and I found this article from [Fabrizio Stellato](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/756476/InnoSetup-Optimize-your-NET-Application-with-ngen) and I was able to get it to work.

I changed this part:

```
[Run]
Filename: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe; Parameters: "install ""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}""";
```

to

```
[Run]
Filename: "{win}\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe"; Parameters: "install ""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" /nologo"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Optimizing..."; Check: IsWin64
```

I added the **{win}** to replace the hard coded **c:\windows**

I hid the **cmd console** with Flags: runhidden;

Show the status to the user with **StatusMsg: "Optimizing...";**

[Fabrizio Stellato](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=5185382) has a complete solution:

[Part 1 InnoSetup, optimize your application with ngen](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754337/InnoSetup-optimize-your-application-with-ngen)

[Part 2 InnoSetup, Optimize your .NET Application with ngen - Part II](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/756476/InnoSetup-Optimize-your-NET-Application-with-ngen?msg=4796507#xx4796507xx)

Regards,

Comment: While using hard-coded path is wrong, as the path can be actually different, if it is not (what it most likely is not), replacing `c:\windows` with `{win}` would not have fixed it. Neither could adding `Flags: runhidden` nor `StatusMsg: "Optimizing..."`. It is more likely that adding of the `WorkingDir: "{app}"` was the fix.